# Using an object in an if statement... (Android)

Tags: java, android, object, if-statement

I have an object variable `Object test = Spinner.getSelectedItem();`
-It gets the selected item from the Spinner (called spinner) and names the item 'test'

I want to do an if statement related to that object e.g:

```
'if (test = "hello") {
//do something
}'
```

But it appears not to work. Do I have to use a different if? or convert the object to string etc.?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The statement:

```
test = "hello"
```

is an assignment of the string "hello" to the variable test - it doesn't do a comparison.

```
test == "hello"
```

is a comparison but still might not work because it compares references.  Two different string instances that happen to be both "hello" may not be the same references and therefore the statement may be false.

Try:

```
"hello".equals( test )
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to compare strings, use *equals()*:

```
if ("hello".equals(test))...
```

Comment: .equals compares objects, not strings. from the java documentation for Object  
boolean  equals(Object obj)
          Indicates whether some other object is "equal to" this one.
Which is inherited by the String class.

Comment: @Tom: of course. I just wanted James to make sure that he is comparing a string with a string (It depends on the type of the items in his Spinner). Otherwise, he will probably receive only false values.

Answer (score 0):

Make test a string and cast the results of getSelectedItem() to a string

```
string test = (string)Spinner.getSelectedItem();
if (test == "hello") 
{
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is also valid in saying test.equals("hello") i don't like the other way it doesn't look right in my coding style.

Comment: You'd have to add an extra null check that way, however. AdapterView#getSelectedItem returns null when nothing is selected.

Comment: I always hated that reasoning.  I prefer to always handle the null case explicitly so that it is clear that I expect null or I don't expect null instead of running the risk of accidentally missing nulls that should not logically happen.